# ASP.Net Multiline Textbox Maxlength

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms, textbox

I've bee searching for a way to limit the text within a TextBox wich looks like this

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbTest" TextMode="MultiLine"  
             MaxLength="20" Rows="5" Columns="30" >
</asp:TextBox>
```

The property  `MaxLength="20"` only works if the other property `TextMode="MultiLine"` is **not** set. It isn't even rendered.

The output in the HTML looks like this:

```
<textarea name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$tbTest" 
          id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_tbTest" rows="5" cols="30">
</textarea>
```

If you search here on SO fo a solution to solve this issue, you get 2 ways suggested:

- add a (`asp:RegularExpression`) validator and validate the control
- add a JavaScript which removes the last insert character in case the limit is reached.

**BUT**

Most of the answer are prevois 2013 and the support of `maxlength` over all browsers was from 2013 as IE10 was released ([reference](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_maxlength.asp)).

Currently every Browser supports this attribute - test it on your own: https://jsfiddle.net/wuu5wne1/

**QUESTION**

How can I force ASP.Net to apply this attribute to my multiline textbox?

Comment: I don't think there was much change in current browsers. You still have to work with JS or a regexp.

Comment: I think if you add MaxLength Attribute from Code Behind it will work, or use html <textarea> and in code behind access the value of textarea

Comment: @ManishGoswami `<textarea>` has any disadvantages compared to `asp:TextBox`?

Comment: so you can try first option..setting attribute from code behind.there is still one option is open use jquery/javascript/Regular Expression

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Welcome to 2020 - this one finally works now on all Browsers

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        tbTest.Attributes.Add("maxlength", "20");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

My solution to this was to just manually set the maxlength property via jquery in document.ready:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $('#<%=tbTest.ClientID%>').prop('maxlength', 20);
}
```

Yeah, it's a bit hacky, but if you want to use the asp control (I didn't want to have to deploy a code change), it works.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2019, `maxLength` will work if you add columns property

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" Columns="1" MaxLength="50" class="form-control"  ID="txtFirstName" ClientIDMode="Static" required />
```

Comment: Not working here. 
 <asp:TextBox TextMode="MultiLine" ID="c_pasteptherapy" Columns="1" MaxLength="100" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>